# How to vertically align HTML text as in a column

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have HTML that looks like this:

```
we already know that: 2*1 = 2
                      2*2 = 4 
                      2*3 = 6
```

(i.e., the numbers are aligned as in a column)

I could use a table, or maybe text-indent.

I'd like to know other options, and what, if any, is "the right way".

Comment: How about `<pre></pre>` tag?

Comment: use table, the output is easy achieve by table

Comment: you can use `css` also, but personally I will use Table, it won't word-wrapped.

Comment: The example is too simplified. You should show a more realistic example. E.g., are there numbers consisting of several digits? How should they be aligned? And asking for “the right way” is generally non-constructive, especially when no criteria have been specified (right for what? to whom?).

Comment: What would you expect for 20 * 3 or 2 * 300 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`<pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag. Quote from w3Schools:

> Text in a `<pre>` element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

Or if that is not an option for you, you can use CSS to set any element to preserve white space by adding [`white-space: pre;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) .

Comment: very nice.
Now ... why would that not be an option for me ? =P

Comment: Sometimes designers don't have the option of changing the HTML markup rendered by developers or the content management system. I guess in your case I could have read from your question that you do have that option, but still it's never a bad thing to have more than one option :)

Comment: The `pre` tag is a blunt instrument, and the desired effect requires a fixed width font. Such fonts are unsuitable for mathematical expressions.

Comment: For some reason, using what space for layout is making me feel unwell. There must be a more semantic option.

Answer (score 2):

My Two cents for a more semantic, non-table solution:

```
<div class="content">we already know that:</div>
<div class="math">
    <div class="eq">
        <span class="operand">2</span><span class="operator">*</span><span class="operand">1</span><span class="operator">=</span><span class="result">2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="eq">
        <span class="operand">2</span><span class="operator">*</span><span class="operand">2</span><span class="operator">=</span><span class="result">4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="eq">
        <span class="operand">2</span><span class="operator">*</span><span class="operand">3</span><span class="operator">=</span><span class="result">2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="eq">
        <span class="operand">2</span><span class="operator">*</span><span class="operand">300</span><span class="operator">=</span><span class="result">600</span>
    </div>
</div>

.content {float:left;}

.math {float:left;}
.math .operand {width: 3em;display: inline-block; }
.math .operator {padding-left: 5px; padding-right:5px }
.math .result {font-weight:bold; text-align:right;width:3em;display: inline-block; }
```

However, having seen the extra markup and reviewing what you have I think a `table` is actually your best solution. You have a table of data with 5 columns, two operand columns, two operator columns and one result column.

http://jsfiddle.net/vnMM2/

**UPdate** Table Version (quick and dirty conversion)

```
<div class="content">we already know that:</div>
<table class="math">
    <tr class="eq">
        <td class="operand">2</td>
        <td class="operator">*</td>
        <td class="operand">1</td>
        <td class="operator">=</td>
        <td class="result">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="eq">
        <td class="operand">2</td>
        <td class="operator">*</td>
        <td class="operand">2</td>
        <td class="operator">=</td>
        <td class="result">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="eq">
        <td class="operand">2</td>
        <td class="operator">*</td>
        <td class="operand">3</td>
        <td class="operator">=</td>
        <td class="result">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="eq">
        <td class="operand">2</td>
        <td class="operator">*</td>
        <td class="operand">300</td>
        <td class="operator">=</td>
        <td class="result">600</td>
    </tr>
</table>

.content {float:left;}
.math {float:left;}
.math td { text-align:right}

.math .result {font-weight:bold }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vnMM2/2/

Answer (score -2):

I am little confused. I am not sure, I may answer you properly. 
If you want to have the Superscript, follow this code:
 "`2 <sup>1</sup> = 2`

> 2 <sup>1</sup> = 2
>
> 2 <sup>2</sup> = 2

Likewise.